# What's my best bet for replacing plain text links with anchor tags in a string? .NET

Tags: .net, url

What is my best option for converting plain text links within a string into anchor tags?

Say for example I have "I went and searched on http://www.google.com/ today". I would want to change that to "I went and searched on [http://www.google.com/](http://www.google.com) today".

The method will need to be safe from any kind of XSS attack also since the strings are user generated. They will be safe before parsing so I just need to make sure that no vulnerabilities are introduced through parsing the URLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple regular expression could get you what you want, since you say that the strings will be safe before parsing.  Just use the following method.

```
private static readonly Regex urlRegex = new Regex(@"(?<Protocol>\w+):\/\/(?<Domain>[\w@][\w.:@]+)\/?[\w\.?=%&=\-@/$,]*", RegexOptions.Compiled);
private static readonly Regex emailRegex = new Regex(@"([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})", RegexOptions.Compiled);
private static readonly IEnumerable<string> disallowedProtocols = new[] { "javascript", "ftp" };
private static string ConvertUrls(string s) {
    s = emailRegex.Replace(
            s,
            match => string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "<a href=\"mailto:{0}\" rel=\"nofollow\">{0}</a>", match.Value)
        );

    s = urlRegex.Replace(
            s,
            match => {
                var protocolGroup = match.Groups["Protocol"];
                if (protocolGroup.Success && !disallowedProtocols.Contains(protocolGroup.Value, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) {
                    return string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "<a href=\"{0}\" rel=\"nofollow\">{0}</a>", match.Value);
                } else {
                    return match.Value;
                }
            }
        );

    return s;
}
```

Comment: I changed my code a bit to disallow certain protocols like "ftp", but if the user just entered "javascript:alert('XSS')", my regular expression wouldn't pick it up, so you'd be safe from this.

Comment: It should be possible to write malicious Javascript that passes your regex (I'm too lazy to make an example), so you do need to disallow `javascript:`.